# How can I sample and show parquet files using fugue?

Tags: fugue

Say I have this file `s3://some/path/some_partiitoned_data.parquet`.

I would like to sample a given count of rows and display them nicely, possibly in a jupyter notebook.

`some_partiitoned_data.parquet` could be very large, I would like to do this without loading the data into memory, even without downloading the parquet files to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Spark doesn't let you sample a given number of rows, you can only sample a given fraction, but with Fugue 0.8.0 this is a solution to get n rows

```
import fugue.api as fa

df = fa.load("parquetfile", engine=spark)
fa.show(fa.sample(df, frac=0.0001), n=10)
```

You just need to make sure with the frac, there are still more than 10 rows.

You can use fa.head to get the dataframe instead of printing it.

See the API reference at https://fugue.readthedocs.io/en/latest/top_api.html